# Can a capped collection be replicated into a regular collection?

Tags: mongodb, replication

I contemplate about a setup where several nodes have capped collections for fast and hassle-free logging. These collection are then replicated to a read-only 'report server' for analysis / reporting and historic data storage.

Can a capped collection be asymmetrically replicated to a regular, non-capped collection?

Comment: I think the best way to do this would be to just insert to both collections (one report collection, and one capped log collection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB does not support that behavior.

Correct support for the behavior is somewhat difficult to define.  For example, what should happen if the unbounded-sized replicas get really far behind, say due to a network partition?  Should the capped collection ignore its cap until the replica catches up, or should the data be lost?